# I can't create clustered index on view in Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server-2014-express, indexed-view

I wanted to create clustered index on view in order to obtain materialized view. Unfortunately the option to create index on view is disabled (faded). Do you know why?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express.

All the best
Bartosz Siemasz

Comment: Have you tried running it as a script? If so what is the error message returning?

Comment: If you like [at the feature comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx), I don't think Express editions support indexed views

Comment: I will try to run it as a script.